# equivalent for servlet in simple java app

Tags: java, path

`request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/Rod")` what is the equivalent for this in simple java app without `servlet`. I have did this with `servlet`, but I don't want to use `servlet` want to use as simple java app.

Comment: What kind of path do you want to get? Give us some examples of paths that you expect and the inputs you have.

Comment: What do you **really** want to do? This smells like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Do you want to load some resources that you ship with your application? Or store some settings?

Comment: that only has meaning in a webapp. What are you trying to do?

Comment: [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718708/get-path-in-java). I want to do this.

Comment: is your app completely java SE ?? (I mean do you ever use servlet anywhere in your app ?)

Comment: [your duplicate post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18718978/1897935) .. there @SotiriosDelimanolis has already answered your question ! if you have any query with answers there then you got to ask it there itself , and not make new questions

Comment: This might help http://www.coderanch.com/t/384661/java/java/find-physical-path-current-java

Comment: @SrinathGanesh my duplicate post's answer say that I need to hard code the path, but I don't want to hard code. If I copy the entire app to another system it should work without any change in code.

Comment: If you had any more points if that answer you should have added a comment in that post . 
Coming to your "copy the entire app to another system" == JUST SEND THE .WAR FILE http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_(Sun)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the absolute path of a file/directory from a relative one:

```
File file = new File("path/to/file");
file.getAbsultePath();
```

Should return you something like: `/home/userid/app_directory/path/to/file`

If you're trying to bundle some resources inside your app, I suggest you to use a different approach, maybe packing the files inside a jar and accesing them by [`getClass().getResource(resourcePath)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)